# Mockito не работает с лямбдами. Бросает MethodNotFoundException

Tags: java, lambda, mockito

Для моканья статических методов используется PowerMockRunner. Но при этом падает на строчках с лямбдами и работает с анонимными классами. Запускается из intellij idea. Зависимости такие:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Пример теста:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class LambdaTest {
@Test
public void testLambda() throws Exception {
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.err.println("anonymous");
        }
    }.run();

    ((Runnable) () ->
            System.err.println("lambda")).run();
}
```

}

Comment: Может Ваш макито безнадёжно устарел. Лямбды пришли с Java 8. Ну это Вы наверняка знаете. А для какой жавы выпущен Ваш макито?

Comment: Т. е. версия 1.6.6 для java 6?

Comment: Не знаю для какой жавы 1.6.6, но краем уха слышал, что для жавы 8 мокито 3, у которого и релиза пока нет.

Comment: Или хотя бы 2.1+ попробуйте

Comment: Попробуйте откатиться на `1.6.4` - https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/717

Comment: На версии 1.6.4 вместо MetodNotFound пишет тест завершен с кодом 254 и в System.out ничего не написал

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не в mockito, а в некорректном кастинге Runnable. Метод run в этом случае остается нереализованным. Это все равно, что написать:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class LambdaTest {
    @Test
    public void testLambda() throws Exception {
        getLambda().run();
    }

    private Runnable getLambda() {
        return () -> System.err.println("lambda");
    }
}
```

Корректная реализация:

```
// Lambda Runnable
Runnable task = () -> System.err.println("lambda");
// Start the thread
new Thread(task).start();
```

Альтернативный вариант:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Runnable task = () -> System.err.println("lambda");
executorService.execute(task);
```

Comment: Тогда для первого варианта будет правильнее написать `new Thread(task).run()`. Но у нас в исходных кодах много вызовов вида `someMethod(x,y () -> {какой-то код});` Оборачивать все в треды неудобно будет